# IBM Rational Rhapsody Generated Files

Tags: clearcase-ucm, rhapsody

I am trying to create an IBM Clearcase development view with a Rational Rhapsody project and need to classify all the private files as checked-in files or generated files.

From what I know all of the .cpp, .h and .o files are auto generated but there are several other file formats I cannot find information on. Does anyone know what a .ehl ,.rpw,  .save, and a .log files are used for? I have been moving files into far off directories and compiling but it takes hours and the help files do not mention these.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see the list of types of files which should be (or not be) under version control at "[Content management files for Rational Rhapsody](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/rhaphlp/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rhp.integ.cm.doc/topics/rhp_r_col_content_mgt_files_for_rational_rhp.html)".
They are also listed at "[Project files and directories](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/rhaphlp/v7r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rhapsody.reference.doc/topics/rhp_r_ref_project_files_directories.html)".

In particular:

- `*.ehl` **Events history list**, which stores animation commands, such as event generation
  **Does not require configuration management**.
- `<Project>.rpw` **Workspace settings file.** Preserves the workspace settings for the project.
  Usually not versioned (private to the user's environment).
- `load.log` A **log of when various repository files were loaded into the product**, including any errors that might have occurred during the loading and resolution phases.
- `store.log`   A **log recording when the project was saved**.
  Both logs shouldn't be versioned.